# adonis in vegan: order of variables or use of strata

Tags: r, vegan

I am using the adonis function in vegan to determine 1) if co-occurring host species vary in their microbial community across multiple sites, and 2) if sites are different. I have examined all posts on CV and SO, and there is no clear answer to how to determine significance of multiple factors using the adonis function.

I first did this, as suggested by [Vegan adonis unbalanced design SS type II or III](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768779/vegan-adonis-unbalanced-design-ss-type-ii-or-iii):

```
## where jacc is a dissimilarity matrix using the jaccard metric
adonis <- adonis(jacc ~ Species + Site, data = df_compare)

# Call:
# adonis(formula = jacc ~ Species + Site, data = df_compare) 
# 
# Permutation: free
# Number of permutations: 999
# 
# Terms added sequentially (first to last)
# 
#           Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)    
# Species    2    0.6055 0.30273  1.7690 0.04981  0.004 ** 
# Site       4    2.1378 0.53445  3.1231 0.17587  0.001 ***
# Residuals 55    9.4122 0.17113         0.77432           
# Total     61   12.1554                 1.00000           
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Then reverse the order

```
adonis_2 <- adonis(jacc ~ Site + Species, data = df_compare)

# Call:
# adonis(formula = jacc ~ Site + Species, data = df_compare) 
# 
# Permutation: free
# Number of permutations: 999
# 
# Terms added sequentially (first to last)
# 
#           Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)    
# Site       4    2.4385 0.60962  3.5623 0.20061  0.001 ***
# Species    2    0.3048 0.15238  0.8904 0.02507  0.716    
# Residuals 55    9.4122 0.17113         0.77432           
# Total     61   12.1554                 1.00000           
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

But I don't know how to interpret that, because the order matters, and I'm not really sure if there are differences among species

After some searching I decided to use strata.

I think this is saying: are co-occurring species different when you only compare species at the same sites.

```
species_adonis <- adonis(jacc ~ Species, strata = df_compare$Site, data = df_compare)

# Call:
# adonis(formula = jacc ~ Species, data = df_compare, strata = df_compare$Site) 
# 
# Blocks:  strata 
# Permutation: free
# Number of permutations: 999
# 
# Terms added sequentially (first to last)
# 
#           Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)
# Species    2    0.6055 0.30273  1.5464 0.04981  0.335
# Residuals 59   11.5500 0.19576         0.95019       
# Total     61   12.1554                 1.00000
```

Then to ask the question about site, I used species in the blocking

I think this is saying: are sites different when you only comparing the same species

```
site_adonis <- adonis(jacc ~ Site, strata = df_compare$Species, data = df_compare)

# Call:
# adonis(formula = jacc ~ Site, data = df_compare, strata = df_compare$Species) 
# 
# Blocks:  strata 
# Permutation: free
# Number of permutations: 999
# 
# Terms added sequentially (first to last)
# 
#           Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)    
# Site       4    2.4385 0.60962  3.5761 0.20061  0.001 ***
# Residuals 57    9.7169 0.17047         0.79939           
# Total     61   12.1554                 1.00000           
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My conclusion is that the microbial community on a given species differs among sites, but that the microbial community does not differ among host species.

Is my approach correct or am I misinterpreting the use of strata (i.e. blocking)?

Or is there a way to somehow average the p-values over the two tests when I switched the order of the variables?

Comment: If you need help with statistical modeling or the interpretation of statistical models then your question would be a better fit for [stats.se]. Right now, this isn't a specific programming question that would be appropriate for Stack Overflow.